# Pybrain: neural network for classification doesn't learn

Tags: python, classification, pybrain

I am trying to use pybrain to classify some inputs (made of 44 variables and the range is from -1 to +1) in 5 classes( from 0 to 4) but I have that the Total error is fixed to around 0.072 even if I change the network structure or I reduce the number of variables in the input vector. The code is:

```
InputT=TrainingINDF.ix[:End,:]
InputT=InputT.as_matrix()
TargetT=TrainingOUTDF.ix[:End,:]
TargetT=TargetT.as_matrix()
ds = ClassificationDataSet(44, 1, nb_classes=5)
for i in range (len(InputT)):
    ds.addSample(InputT[i,:],TargetT[i])
testdata=ClassificationDataSet(44, 1, nb_classes=5)
for i in range (len(TrainingINDF.ix[StartTS:,:])):
    testdata.addSample(TrainingINDF.ix[StartTS+i,:],TrainingOUTDF.ix[StartTS+i])
testdata._convertToOneOfMany()
ds._convertToOneOfMany()
net = buildNetwork(44,15,5,hiddenclass=TanhLayer, outclass=SoftmaxLayer)
trainer = BackpropTrainer(net,dataset=ds,momentum=0.1,verbose=True, weightdecay=0.01) 
trnerr,valerr = trainer.trainUntilConvergence(dataset=ds,maxEpochs=100)
ris = net.activateOnDataset(testdata)
out=ris.argmax(axis=1)
percenterrortest=percentError(out, testdata['class'] )
print 'Percent Error on Test dataset: ' , percentError(trainer.testOnClassData (dataset=testdata ), testdata['class'] )
print 'Percent Error on Train dataset: ' , percentError(trainer.testOnClassData (dataset=ds ), ds['class'] )
```

The  test percent error is 61.93, and the train percent error is 60.50. 
What am I doing wrong? 
What is surprising me is that the 3 errors ( the precentages and the total error) are  always around the same values; no matter what I change.

Thank you

Comment: I looked at the values inside  'out'  and I saw that class 1 and 3 are never between the output values. Do you have any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not super familiar with PyBrain but, are you sure the output is capable of being less than 0?  If the output is constrained to be between 0 and 1, for example, it might never be able to get very close to the right answer.

Comment: Actually, the output is between 0 and 1 because since it is a classification problem,  I associated to 4- 1, to 3 - 0.75 and so on. So what would you suggest?

Comment: Is the value "3" actually in between "4" and "2"?  Or are these arbitrary labels which just happen to be numbers?  If the latter, then four different outputs, each a yes-no for one of the classifications, might work better.

Comment: I already have 5 binary outputs  for the classification as they suggest in pybrain...

Comment: So, when you say you associated 3 to 0.75, what do you mean?  Is the "3" an output type, or do you mean level 3 out of 4?

Comment: Since I was not sure that it worked with classes from 0 to 4 I  divided all the output vector by 4 in order to have the output in the range [0,1]; it is actually not important it. What really is annoying me is that the Total error is fixed to 0.072, no matter what I change.

Comment: I was just trying to make sure that "3" is actually more similar to "4" and "2" than it is to "1".  Because if these are just labels to different outcomes, that aren't really numeric, then it would be difficult for the network to learn.

Comment: yes they are more like labels so what would you suggest? (do you know a good python lbrary for neural network not based on theano)?

Comment: Each class should have its own output neuron, and the target should be "1" if that class is present, "0" if it is not.  So, if the target is "3", then output neuron "3" has target of "1", and output neurons "1", "2", and "4" have target of "0".